# 2 Xbox Live accounts signed into 1 console?

Tags: xbox-network

I have an XBL account, have for awhile.

When my nephew comes over he is always playing on my account but he has his own account at his house on his xbox.

Is there a way for him to sign into his account on my Xbox? Can he bring it with him some how?  Will his data sync to his Xbox or whats the deal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, he can either bring his profile with him on a Memory card or USB stick (assuming you both have updated your consoles). I do this regularly when going to a friends house.

He could also recover his account onto your Xbox, but that is a bit more of a hassle.

Achievements and other online stats are synced in either case (as long as you are connected to the internet), but saved game files won't be transferred if he recovers his account (or if he doesn't bring them on his memory card/usb stick).

Comment: Is there a tutorial that an 8 yr old could understand to bring his profile with him on a thumb drive?

Comment: @Mike http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/kb.aspx?ID=907698&lcid=1033&category=live

Comment: For people with a 360 S, remind your friends to bring USB sticks - there are no memory card slots as there were with the older models.

Answer (score 1):

If they have Xbox Live on their account, they can recover the account at your house, then do the same when they get home.

As far as data syncing goes, it varies from small amounts to none. Stuff like weapons unlocked in multiplayer game modes usually do, larger stuff like single player progress usually (maybe always) doesn't.

Comment: The only information that is recovered through Microsoft is profile information: friends, games list, gamerscore, and achievements. Individual games may track things on their servers that you access through your account, and in those cases, you might have access to features you've previously unlocked.

Comment: Since this is an old answer, you can now do this without having to recover when you get back home. The account is saved to any console you recover it on. Single player progress is normally recorded in saves on your HDD. You can save this to the could service (instead of your local HDD) if you want to access it on multiple consoles though.